# jQuery: Print only one result from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a set of arrays in `json` as followed:

```
{"status":200,"success":true,"result":
[{"id":"0","NameInData":"","name":"","type":"mf","greeting":"Bonjour","message":"GENERIC: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"1","NameInData":"alexis","name":"Alexis","type":"mf","greeting":"Bonjour Alexis","message":"ONE: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"2","NameInData":"laurence","name":"Laurence","type":"ff","greeting":"Hello Laurence","message":"TWO: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"3","NameInData":"francois","name":"Francois","type":"mm","greeting":"Konnichiwa Francois","message":"THREE: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"4","NameInData":"dirk","name":"Dirk","type":"mf","greeting":"Ni hao Dirk","message":"FOUR: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"5","NameInData":"coline","name":"Coline","type":"ff","greeting":"high 5! Coline","message":"FIVE: Lorem ipsum."}]}
```

I am able to identify the value of a key from this array, and `//do something` with it with the following code:

```
$.each(json.result, function(){
    if (this.name == content){
        //do something
        var identifiedID =  this.id;
        console.log("PRINT ID: " + identifiedID);

        var name = json.result[identifiedID].name;                  
        var $nameText = $("#nameText"),
            str = name;
            html = $.parseHTML(str),
            nodeNames = [];
            $nameText.append(html);
        console.log("Name: " + name);
    } else {
        var identifiedID = 0;
        console.log("PRINT ID: " + identifiedID);   

        var name = content;                 
        var $nameText = $("#nameText"),
            str = name;
            html = $.parseHTML(str),
            nodeNames = [];
            $nameText.append(html);
        console.log("Name: " + name);
});
```

I am trying to `//do other things` if the `name` is not unidentified within the list with the following code. However, as my array has 6 items, the output would be repeating the whole process 6 times, where I would only want one output, one result (either, a name and its id has been identified and print what it is related to OR a name has not been recognised and the id would be set to 0 and print what it is related.)

You may find my full code in the link [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/17/).
It would be very nice if someone could tell me which part of my syntax is wrong please?

Comment: You referred to json object in your question but your fiddle is missing that.

Comment: Uh...can you always be sure that `{"id": "3"...` will be at index [3]? Because if that's not a certainty, I can see a gap in your logic.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first element that matches a condition (i.e. `name == content`), defaulting to the first element of `json.result` if none is found (assuming `json.result[0]` is always the default case).

```
var item = json.result.find(function(e) {
    return e.name == content;
}) || json.result[0];

console.log("PRINT ID: " + item.id);

var name = item.name || content;                  
var $nameText = $("#nameText"),
    str = name;
    html = $.parseHTML(str),
    nodeNames = [];
    $nameText.append(html);
console.log("Name: " + name);
```

Note this code makes the assumption that `name != ""` for non-default items that you're looking for.

I'm not sure what you're doing with `nodeNames` but if you're just trying to set the text of `#nameText` to the name, you can simply use `$('#nameText').text(name);`

Answer (score 1):

you could just exit the each function in your if statement once your condition is met with.

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the JSFiddle code you should use $.grep() instead of $.each() to filter out items matching your condition, i.e.- name. $.grep() returns the array of matched elements. So you can check if the the length of the array is greater than 0. If yes you have found a match. If not there is no matching element.

Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question I would say that syntax looks correct...